# How to validate large data set from PowerShell against SQL server table

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, powershell, dataset

I have couple hundred rows of data of about 100 bytes each and need the field values validated against fairly large (milions of rows) table in SQL server. The query itself on SQL is very quick, but running single query per row from the script is not slow, probably because of the connection set-up and teardown. I can't add any stored procs to the server. Is there any way how to pass a dataset/table to a query from the script and return results rather then iterate the dataset row-by-row? Of course PowerShell code samples would be welcome ;)

Answer (score -1):

There won't be a way via powershell (or any other method I am aware of) as SQL Server can't accept a table as an input parameter in a query.  Any method you use for this will at some point be passing a row/specific values to SQL.

What you COULD do is create a table from your array and compare that temp table to your large table for validation.  Determining if this is faster will need some testing, though.

Comment: Actually SQL 2008 added table valued parameters which all you to pass a table to a query, but their use requires creating a server-side object-- user defined table type. If you can't create any server-side side objects, then I agree temp table and parsing array of values is next best option.